# Complicated nested array issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to query data from a database into a json array that ultimalty produces a force    directed graph in javascript. Here is what the Json array should be like. However nodes can have mulitiple adjacencies or none, how can I query a json array where the adjacencies section varies from node to node and is able to adjust according to the number of adjacencies a node has?

```
Var JSON =[ 
 {
  "adjacencies": [
    {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode9", 
      "nodeFrom": "graphnode5", 
      "data": {}
    }
  ], 
  "data": {
    "$color": "#416D9C", 
    "$type": "star"
  }, 
  "id": "graphnode5", 
  "name": "graphnode5"
},
];
```

or they can have

```
Var JSON =[ 
 {
  "adjacencies": [
    {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode9", 
      "nodeFrom": "graphnode5", 
      "data": {}
    },
    {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode9", 
      "nodeFrom": "graphnode5", 
      "data": {}
    },
    {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode9", 
      "nodeFrom": "graphnode5", 
      "data": {}
    }
  ], 
  "data": {
    "$color": "#416D9C", 
    "$type": "star"
  }, 
  "id": "graphnode5", 
  "name": "graphnode5"
},
];
```

or they can not have any

```
Var JSON =[ 
 {
  "adjacencies": [], 
  "data": {
    "$color": "#416D9C", 
    "$type": "star"
  }, 
  "id": "graphnode5", 
  "name": "graphnode5"
},
];
```

Here is my attempt so far, however this only produces a json that only allows one adjacencies, How can I setup a Json query that will adjust the the number of adjacencies a node have? while just loading the data and id section once but allowing the adjacenies to be varied?

Here is my Database structure

```
nodes                 Relationships                      
-----                 -------------
id int(11),           id int(11),
name varchar(35),    goingto int(11), //this is the destination node from the id relation 
color varchar(7),     data varchar(0) null
type varchar (12),    Foreign key (id) references nodes(id)
Primary key (id)       

engine = innodb
```

And here is my attempt that

```
function getjson(){  
 $db = adodbConnect();
$query = "SELECT nodes.*, relationships.* FROM nodes inner JOIN relationships ON nodes.id =   relationships.id";
$result = $db -> Execute($query);

while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
  $id= (float)$row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $color1 = $row['color'];
  $type1 = $row['type'];
  $to= (float)$row['goingto']; 
  $thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path

  $array[] = array(
  "adjacencies" => array( array(
  "nodeTo" => "$to",
  "nodeFrom" => "$id",
  "data" => array() )),
  "data" => array(
  "$"."color" => $color1,
  "$"."type" => $type1 ),
  "id" => $id,
  "name" => "<img src='".$thumb."' height='25' width='25' alt='root'/><label>".$name."</label>");
}

$json = json_encode($array);
print "$json";
//return $json;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you never get an empty list of adjacencies? If that's the problem, use a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: No everything loads properly but to load the id and data array for each node once but have the adjacencies mulitple times while keeping the structure of the over all array.

Comment: @user1902588 It appears you've asked this same question 3 times. This one, and then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608156/array-with-multiple-sizes-query-from-database-issue) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714467/multideminsional-array-query-iteration-issue).  That last one was closed, and I will be recommending the other one closed as well as it has no answers/comments etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the result in a single query, then you will end up with duplicated data for the node, in each separate row where there's a distinct adjacency from that node...  Which is fine, that's how it works.

But as it sits, you won't get nodes returned if there's no adjacency on that node (because you're using an `INNER join`. You should use a `LEFT join` to include nodes that have no results from the related adjacency table).

By sorting by node `id`, we explicitly ensure that all nodes and their adjacencies appear grouped together. This is probably happening already because `id` is your pk and hence the sort is happening this way "automatically". But an `ORDER BY nodes.id` ensures this happens, and makes your intention clear to anyone looking at the code.

Also, because you're returning everything `*` from both tables, you're going to have column name conflicts, on `node.id` and `relationship.id`.  Ideally you'd explicitly name your columns to avoid this so that you have predictable results back in PHP.

So your SQL could look more like:

```
SELECT 
    n.id as n_id,
    n.name,
    n.color,
    n.type,
    r.id as r_id,
    r.goingto,
    r.data 

FROM 
    nodes n

    LEFT JOIN relationships r
    ON n.id = r.id

ORDER BY
    n.id
```

This returns a result set that looks something like:

```
n_id  | name  | color  |  type | r_id | goingto |  data 
------+-------+--------+-------+------+---------+-----------
1     | node1 | red    | type1 | 1    | 5       | stuff 
1     | node1 | red    | type1 | 2    | 6       | morestuff 
2     | node2 | blue   | type2 | 3    | 10      | whatever 
3     | node3 | green  | type3 | null | null    | null 
4     | node4 | orange | type4 | 4    | 20      | xxx1 
4     | node4 | orange | type4 | 5    | 21      | xxx2 
4     | node4 | orange | type4 | 6    | 22      | xxx3

etc...
```

(ie this assumes node 1 has two relationships, node 2 has 1 relationship, node 3 has no relationships, and node 4 has 3).

And then, your code that builds the array just needs to iterate the results, building a new node only when the current record's node is not the same as the previous one (ie we're relying on the `ORDER BY node.id` to "gather" all the info for a particular node, sequentially).

This code hasn't been tested, but I think the intent is clear, you should be able to bend this as required - but it basically just implements the above.

Replace your `while` loop with all of this.

```
$previd = -1;
while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
    $id= (float)$row['n_id']; // <--- note change from 'id' to 'n_id'
    $name = $row['name'];
    $color1 = $row['color'];
    $type1 = $row['type'];
    $to= (float)$row['goingto']; 
    $thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path

    // Is this row the start of a new node?    
    if ($previd != $id) {
        // Yes, new node.  Record our new node id, for future new node checks.
        $previd = $id; 

        // Store the previous node we've already built, now that it's complete (but only if there was a previous node!)
        if ($previd != -1) {
            $array.push($node);
        }

        // Start our new node off, ready to accept adjacencies
        $node = array(
            "adjacencies" => array(),
            "data" => array(
                    "$"."color" => $color1,
                    "$"."type" => $type1 
                ),
            "id" => $id,
            "name" => "<img src='".$thumb."' height='25' width='25' alt='root'/><label>".$name."</label>");
    } 

    // Any adjacency for this node, on this row?
    if ($to != null) { // <-- Not sure about this line!
        // Yes there is, so create the new adjacency record and add it to the current node's adjacency array.
        $node["adjacencies"].push(
            array(
                "nodeTo" => "$to",
                "nodeFrom" => "$id",
                "data" => array() 
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how "no adjacency" will be represented in `$to` - ie if this will be "null" or what.  I'll leave that to you to test, but suffice to say you'll need to reflect this in the line `if ($to != null) { // <-- Not sure about this line!`

Comment: sepster you have taught me more in this excerpt regarding sql statements then my database theory teacher. Im profoundly thankful for your help.

Comment: @user1902588 my pleasure mate, really glad you found it useful. Thanks for the accept, I really appreciate it.